# Is there a way to post an automatic comment for every new Like on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

As the title says, I'm wondering if there is a way for adding a "Thank you" post or comment on a Facebook page for each new Like on that page. 
The comment should of course contain the linked username of the thanked user.

For example something like

> Thank you *username* for your like. Make sure to visit all our photo albums.

Comment: Do you have any programming experience? You could create a small application using the Facebook API to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

No. Currently this feature is not available. You have to do this manually.